# Why boolean value in Python is 24/28 bytes?

Tags: data-structures, python

What is the reason for this behavior? Usually, in other programming languages, it is either 4/8 bytes, if I am correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A boolean value can be represented with just one bit, but are usually
four or eight bytes long in most statically typed languages because
dealing with values smaller than the register size (four or eight
bytes) can be inconvenient. But Python is object-oriented and
dynamically typed, meaning that every value is an object and that
every value carries information about its type. So you need a lot of
metadata you otherwise wouldn't need.

Looking at Python' source code, you'll see that bools are actually
implemented as long integers having the values 0 or 1. And "long
objects" are defined as follows:

```
typedef struct _PyLongValue {
    uintptr_t lv_tag; /* Number of digits, sign and flags */
    digit ob_digit[1];
} _PyLongValue;

struct _longobject {
    PyObject_HEAD
    _PyLongValue long_value;
};
```

`PyObject_HEAD` is an alias for `PyObject`, defined as:

```
typedef struct {
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;   /* object reference count */
    PyTypeObject* ob_type;  /* object type */
};
```

If we sum the sizes of all the structs' members, we get 28 bytes in
total; 8 for `ob_refcnt`, 8 for `ob_type`, 8 for `lv_tag` and 4 for
`ob_digit[1]`.

Isn't using 28 bytes for a single boolean wasteful? Probably not since
memory allocators allocate memory in chunks to reduce bookkeeping. I
haven't checked, but I guess that the smallest chunk Python can
allocate is 32 bytes. So it doesn't matter if the object is one byte
or 28 bytes. Furthermore, there will never be more than two boolean
values in the runtime since every reference to true and
every reference to false points to the same object.

Comment: Most of this is specific to CPython. There is no reason to assume that every implementation of Python must use the same encoding. Certainly, there is nothing in the Python language specification which requires it. I am willing to bet that at least GraalPython does not use the same encoding.